# Get last price by user role?

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

How do I get the last price claimed by the retailer b@gmail.com (the 5th row in the price table) with the condition that the role = 'retailer' ?

So here is my simple table:

table **users** (using Entrust Role package with the default relationship in the model)

```
 __________________________
| id | email   | password |
|-------------------------|
| 1  | a@g.com | 123      |
| 2  | b@g.com | 123      |
| 3    c@g.com | 123      |
| 4    d@g.com | 123      |
--------------------------
```

table **roles** (using Entrust Role package with the default relationship in the model)

```
 ______________
|id |  name    |
|--------------|
|1  | customer |
|2  | retailer |
----------------
```

table **role_user** (using Entrust Role package with the default relationship in the model)

```
 __________________
|id_user |  id_role|
|------------------|
|  1     |    1    |  -> a@gmail.com is a customer
|  2     |    2    |  -> b@gmail.com is a retailer
|  3     |    1    |  -> c@gmail.com is a customer
|  4     |    1    |  -> d@gmail.com is a customer
 ------------------
```

Here is the tricky part how to query the price:

I have the following **prices** table (Users can post 1 or more prices. Look at the relationship below):

```
 ____________________
|id|  user_id| price |
|--------------------|
|1 |    1    | 10.00 | -> price claimed by a customer a@gmail.com
|2 |    2    |  5.00 | -> price claimed by a retailer b@gmail.com
|3 |    1    |  6.00 | -> price claimed by a previous customer a@gmail.com
|4 |    3    |  5.00 | -> price claimed by a customer c@gmail.com
|5 |    2    |  7.00 | -> price claimed by a previous retailer b@gmail.com //How to get this one? This is the last price claimed by the retailer.
|6 |    3    |  8.00 | -> price claim by a customer c@gmail.com
---------------------
```

The relationship in my **Price** model:

```
class Price extends Model{
  public function product()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
  }

  public function user()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }
```

How do I get the last price claimed by the retailer b@gmail.com (the 5th row in the price table) with the condition that the role = 'retailer' ?

The purpose is to get the last price that the retailer has claimed.

**Update my question:**
I want to access the price claimed by the last retailer from my **Product** model using the **$products** variable.

A sample table **product** that I have:

```
_______________________________
|id      |  user_id| name     |
|------------------------------
|  1     |    1    | Milk     |
|  2     |    2    | Phone    |
|  3     |    1    | computer |
|  4     |    1    | Banana   |
 ------------------------------
```

My **Product.php** model relationship:

```
class Product extends Model{

 public function prices()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Price');
 }
}
```

So, in my **ProductController.php** I send the $**product** variable to the view like this:

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
 public function show($id)
 {
  $product = Product::where('id', '=', $id)->
  return view('products.show')->with('product', $product);
 }
```

}

and in my view **show.blade.php**, I loop through the **$product** variables and I can display the prices claimed for the product.

```
@foreach($product->prices as $price)
    <li>Price claimed: {{$price->price. " " }} </li>
@endforeach
```

I want to get like something like

```
 $price_last = $product->prices()->where(role, 'retailer')->last(). 

 dd($price_last);
```

The last() function there is the last price that the retailer claimed but this code is just example. How do I achieve this?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`whereHas`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method:

```php
$query = Price::latest('id')->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('role', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'retailer');
    });
});

$price = $query->value('price');
```

This assumes you've set up the relationships between your `User`, `Role` and `Price` models.

Comment: Hai @Joseph thanks for your answer. The answer that you have given does not work in my situation. It took me a while to update the question again. I want to get the price from my Product model. I have setup all the relationship (question updated). Something like $product->prices()->where(role, 'retailer')->last().  How do I setup this relationship.

Comment: @MaXi32 - Just replace `Price::latest('id')` with `$product->prices()->latest('id')`

Comment: I just tried out the solution but I got an error (I updated the solution with the error). BTW, the user and the role in the codes are they tables name and should be plurals?

Comment: Hi, the code works (i made a mistake in the relationship), but, I have another question, Can I omit the condition where ('email', 'b@gmail.com')? I just want to query the role part. Is that possible?